# Device stop receive push notification from Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I developed an App that receives push notifications from Google Cloud Messaging, messages are sent to broadcast from a server in php through the procedure CURL. Everything is working fine but a device (Android 4.3) a few days does not receive notifications from GCM.

Question: Is there any way (in PHP) to reclaim such registration id are still valid or need to be renewed?

I know the id registration must be renewed when the app is updated or uninstalled and then reinstalled it in this case was not made any changes.
In this device other notifications arrive correctly (whatsapp, sms).
For my app does not have disabled notifications.
I have not updated or uninstalled the app for groped to understand whether the problem is the device or something more obscure.

Now GCM return this (not error):
{"multicast_id":6846627542248171696,"success":3,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1442178661471816%5ed68546f7f47ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1442178661471814%5ed68546f7f47ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1442178661472121%5ed68546f7f47ecd"}]}

The DEVICE not receive push notification is 3 but CURL operation return true.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Huuummm I think is not possible with PHP CURL operation... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified that the problem was related to the device and not the Bees google for the non-receipt of the message.
An operation CURL but can not return the entire state of the message because of the fact that it is a synchronous operation. I noticed from the console that can pass several minutes before the device returns the code Accepted.
The only way to confirm the message was received by the device seems to be an asynchronous operation with an appropriate Java server.